# Find json element within object and remove it

Tags: jquery, json

Using jquery, how would I go about finding the index of a JSON object.

Below is what is created:

```
[{"itemid":3,"itemName":"Some text here","itemPrice":"£2.40"},{"itemid":3,"itemName":"Some text here","itemPrice":"£2.40"},{"itemid":2,"itemName":"Some text here","itemPrice":"£2.40"}]
```

Here is how it translates in console:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
itemName: "Some text here"
itemPrice: "£2.40"
itemid: 3
__proto__: Object
1: Object
itemName: "Some text here"
itemPrice: "£2.40"
itemid: 3
__proto__: Object
2: Object
itemName: "Some text here"
itemPrice: "£2.40"
itemid: 2
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
```

If i wanted to look through the string by searching for the itemid as the value to find, and then go back and remove it from the string using splice, what would the code look like.  I keep getting odd errors.

Here is the code i have:

This creates the json string:
    var item = {"itemid" : itemId, "itemName" : itemName, "itemPrice" : itemPrice};

```
cOrder.push(item);
localStorage.setItem('cOrder', JSON.stringify(cOrder));
```

Here i search through the string to get the the right element to remove:

```
var itemid = ($(this).text());
console.log(cOrder);
$.each(cOrder, function(key, value) {
    if(value.itemid == itemid) {
    // Here i need to get the index of the object //
    console.log(Object.keys(cOrder).indexOf(this));
    }
});
```

Using the above as a working example.  If i wanted to remove itemid 3, I need to remove object index 1 (1 : Object)

How do I get that index 1, and then remove it from the string ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't `var itemid = ($(this).text());` making `itemid` a string? And with `if(value.itemid == itemid) {` you are comparing an integer with a string? JavaScript type comparisons throw me off sometimes...

Comment: I am not sure to be honest.  when I look for a itemid, it does fire a true IF statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With arrays, you can't start at the beginning of the array in a loop and remove items... if you do that the loop counter and the index will get off from each other. You may need to create a second array and add the valid items to the secondary array during the loop.

Items matching the id:

```
var validItems = [];
$.each(cOrder, function(key, value) {
    if(value.itemid == itemid) {
        validItems.push(value);
    }
});
```

Items not matching the id:

```
var validItems = [];
$.each(cOrder, function(key, value) {
    if(value.itemid != itemid) {
        validItems.push(value);
    }
});
```

Or both:

```
var validItems = [];
var invalidItems = [];
$.each(cOrder, function(key, value) {
    if(value.itemid == itemid) 
        validItems.push(value);
    else
        invalidItems.push(value);
});
```

**Update**

This may help your quantity issue. You would have to add a `itemQuantity` property to your object to support this. With that property, you could create a function like this:

```
//quantity can be positive or negative
function adjustItemQuantity(itemId, quantity, remove) {
    //if no quantity, or quantity==0, and not remove then nothing to do here
    if (!quantity && !remove) return;

    //create the temporary array
    var validItems = [];

    $.each(cOrder, function(key, value) {
        if(value.itemid == itemId) {
            var newQuantity = value.itemQuantity + quantity;

            //remove if quantity 0 or less
            if (newQuantity > 0 && !remove)
                validItems.push(value);
        } else {
            //add the other, non-matching items to the array
            validItems.push(value);
        }
    });

    //set the main array to the new result
    cOrder = validItems;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, it did not cross my mind at all to do that.  Thank you buddy.

Comment: There is logic problem with this, in that if the person orders several of the same item (ie same itemid) and removes all of them instead of just one.  Trying to decide what the best approach will be for this ?

Comment: So there is a quantity variable in the mix as well. Your object already has a name, id, and description. Probably should add a quantity property. I went ahead and updated my answer with a possible solution...